# Angularjs $watch tree array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an tree array like this:

```
Array
(
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [attribute_group_id_6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => Processor
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [product_id] => 40
                                    [attr_id] => 1
                                    [attr_text] => demo
                                    [attr_group_id] => 6
                                    [attr_group_order] => 1
                                    [attr_group_name] => Processor
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [product_id] => 28
                                    [attr_id] => 2
                                    [attr_text] => 10
                                    [attr_group_id] => 6
                                    [attr_group_order] => 5
                                    [attr_group_name] => Processor
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [product_id] => 28
                                    [attr_id] => 3
                                    [attr_text] => 777
                                    [attr_group_id] => 6
                                    [attr_group_order] => 3
                                    [attr_group_name] => Processor
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
    )
```

And the goal is to wathc `items.[N].product_id` change.

This code can see changes but, it see all 3 changes at once.

```
$scope.$watch('filterData.attributes.items', function(val, old) {
   console.log('watch');
}, true);

console:
watch
watch
watch
```

Values are changed via text field:

The questin is - how to watch only one change? `(attributes.attribute_group_id_6.items.[N].product_id)`

Comment: One thing not clear is: are there 3 changes or just one change triggered multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback triggers for each change in the whole `items` Array. What you acutally need is a listener for each single item, which you can create within a loop - though JSHint might not like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filterData.attributes.items.length; i++) {
  $scope.$watch('filterData.attributes.items[' + i + ']', function(val, old) {
    console.log('watch');
  }, true);
}
```